# How to add a Node Module's script from the package.json file to the Root package.json file

Tags: json, npm, npm-scripts

I'm making an NPM that would make setting up Bootstrap 4 for live editing faster with 1 command (after installing).

I have a few `script` in my **custom_Module** `package.json` file that I want to programmatically add to the **Root** `package.json` file in the `script` definition.

How would I go about it?

I can install the dependency modules, but I cannot run the commands with `npm run SCRIPTNAME`

**custom_module**:

```js
"script":{
           "kenobi": "node-sass --watch scss -o dist/css";
           "hellothere": "concurrently \"npm run kenobi\" \"live-server --port=66\""
}
```

note: I want to move these `script` to the root `package.json` file.

File structure for reference:

```
ROOT
   -package.json  //Root package.json
    ...
   -node_module
      -custom_Module
         -package.json. // Node Module's package.json
```

Answer (score 0):

Feature is not available.

You're just going to need to add the script to the Root `package.json`.